# Ranger syncing with unix users

Tags: hadoop, apache-ranger

I have created two empty groups on two differentt nodes of my cluster, just one on each node. My ranger service uses unix user synchronization, when I restart the Ranger service I cant see my added groups to cluster nodes in Ranger UI, I use HDP 2.5. How to sync my ranegr with unix users?

Comment: Typically, you use LDAP/AD, not Unix accounts for syncing https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/105620/configuring-ranger-usersync-with-adldap-for-a-comm.html

Answer (score 0):

As you try to sync users, you already seem to understand that there are users for the os, and users for the hadoop platform.

Typically OS users are admin/ops people who need to manage the environment, while most platform users are engineers, analysts, and other who want to do something on the platform. This large group of users is something you typically want to sync.

As already indicated by @cricket you can integrate with LDAP/AD as explained here:
https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/105620/configuring-ranger-usersync-with-adldap-for-a-comm.html